# Product of the cycles of permutation group

Tags: group-theory, permutations

I was studying permutation group, and I got a doubt, that (12345) can be written as (54)(52)(21)(25)(23)(13) ! Instead of (54)(53)(52)(51). But how this transposition be done .can I do anything ? Can I do in someway?

Comment: I'm not sure what your are asking. Is your question one of these? "Is it possible to write a permutation as a product of transpositions in more than one way?" "Is $(12345)=(54)(52)(21)(25)(23)(13)=(54)(53)(52)(51)$ correct?" "How can I show $(54)(52)(21)(25)(23)(13)=(54)(53)(52)(51)$?"

Comment: Yes absolutely I want to know how many way I can write with length 2

Comment: Can I write (12345) another ways except these 3 cyclic notation

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking whether or not if $(12345)$ can be written as $(54)(52)(21)(25)$? You can compute these and see whether or not this is the case. Note usually with cycle notation we have that unique elements should only appear in the cycle decomposition once.